# default selector for imageButton in Android

Tags: android, xml, selector, imagebutton

I'm trying to locate the Android XML and drawable files that are used by default for imageButtons.

I'm trying to customise an imageButton using a selector. When I create a new project, by default the background color of an imageButton is transparent-grey and it gets highlighted in blue when touched.  (I'm SDK-19 and .Light theme). To avoid the hassles of re-creating lots of icons, I want to find the default XML selector code and 9.pngs Android uses for an imageButton.

Looking in the SDK android-19/data/res/drawable folder there are a bunch of XML selectors defined in files with names like "btn_default_holo_light" "btn_default_transparent" etc., and a bunch of button drawables in .../drawable-hdpi.

I can pick any of these, copy it into a "my_selector.XML" file in my project's drawable folder (plus copy the necessary drawables into my projects drawable_hdpi), and set "my_selector" as my imageButton's background. This all works fine...Except none of the SDK files I've found results in the default "blue when touched" effect (some turn the imageButton orange, others do nothing...).

I'm sure the default files are right there under my nose but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find them!

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you won't find the default images you are looking for in the SDK files. The default images can vary from device to device, rather than from android version to android version. The effect you are looking for is probably specific to your device/emulator.

> "The appearance of your button (background image and font) may vary from one device to another, because devices by different manufacturers often have different default styles for input controls."

[Reference^^](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

If you just want to get the images and copy them, you may be able to find them on the actual device by activating [USB Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and searching through the usually hidden folders on your particular device. The storage of those files probably vary between devices so I am afraid I can't tell you where they are (*some files are kept hidden even with Debugging active. In those cases apps such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en_GB) might be able to help*). Although this probably wasn't the answer you were looking for I hope this helps.